# how can I capture the expanded forms?

Tags: racket

I'm trying to capture the expanded forms by defining my own `module-begin`:

```
(define-syntax-rule (my-module-begin e ...)
  (#%module-begin            
   e ...
  (foo e ...)))
```

Am I correct that `foo` here gets the original forms? If so is there a way for `foo` to get the expanded forms instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the expanded forms you'll need to use [`local-expand`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxtrans.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._local-expand%29%29) in some way.

#### Part 1, an incomplete solution

You might think to call [`local-expand`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxtrans.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._local-expand%29%29) separately on every expression like this:

```
#lang racket

(require syntax/parse/define
         (for-syntax syntax/stx))

(define-simple-macro (my-module-begin e ...)
  ; define a function that expands it
  #:do [(define (expand/mod-ctx e)
          (local-expand e 'module '()))]
  ; get the expanded versions by calling that function on the e's
  #:with (e-expanded ...) (stx-map expand/mod-ctx #'(e ...))
  ; use the expanded versions inside foo
  (#%module-begin            
   e-expanded ...
   (foo e-expanded ...)))
```

This works when the `e` forms are *expressions* like `(+ 1 2)` or `(let ([x 3] [y 4]) (make-list x y))`. However, it doesn't work when the `e` forms can be definitions.

#### Part 2, getting the expanded versions from Racket's `#%module-begin`

One way to support using [`local-expand`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxtrans.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._local-expand%29%29) with these module-level definitions is to wrap it in racket's `#%module-begin` form before expanding. This allows it to process all the `e`s *together* in one call to [`local-expand`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxtrans.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._local-expand%29%29).

```
(define-simple-macro (my-module-begin e ...)
  ; get the expanded versions by calling that function on a
  ; *constructed* module-begin form
  #:with (_ e-expanded ...) (local-expand #'(#%module-begin e ...) 'module-begin '())
  ; use the expanded versions inside foo
  (#%module-begin            
   e-expanded ...
   (foo e-expanded ...)))
```

This gets Racket's `#%module-begin` to handle the definitions, and when it's done, you can pattern match on it with `(_ e-expanded ...)`.